# reverse next() in Python generator

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, generator

Let's say that we have the following code:

```
gen = (x for x in range(11))

for el in gen:
    print("Printing current element: ", el) #1
    if el % 3 == 0:
        print("The next item is: ", next(gen)) #2
```

In this example I would like to print all the numbers from the generator in line `#1` and additionally those divisible by 3 in line `#2`. The code must use element-wise (as opposed to index-wise) iteration. There's also a restriction that the generator `gen` must stay a generator (due to memory-limitations) and cannot be used e.g. as a list in `reversed(list(gen))`.

Current implementation makes the iteration skip numbers due to `next(gen)`.

Comment: Shouldn't you need `"The next item is: ", el`? (as you say you need to print those divisible by 3 in this line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.tee` to replicate the iterable, displace the replicated iterable by an offset of 1 with a call of `next`, and then use `itertools.zip_longest` to pair the two iterables for iteration:

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest
gen = (x for x in range(11))
a, b = tee(gen)
next(b)
for el, n in zip_longest(a, b):
    print("Printing current element: ", el)
    if el % 3 == 0:
        print("The next item is: ", n)
```

This outputs:

```
Printing current element:  0
The next item is:  1
Printing current element:  1
Printing current element:  2
Printing current element:  3
The next item is:  4
Printing current element:  4
Printing current element:  5
Printing current element:  6
The next item is:  7
Printing current element:  7
Printing current element:  8
Printing current element:  9
The next item is:  10
Printing current element:  10
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the current element print-out for number 10?